# How to access a MySQL database from a client using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, client-server

I'm using two computers, namely Computer A and Computer B.

Computer A stands as a server for my computer which holds a MySQL database and Computer B stands as a client.

Both of them were connected to a Wi-Fi switch.
Computer B holds this C# type of code to connect into database of Computer A.

```
connectionString="Server=;Database=studentdb;Uid=thesis;Pwd=12345;
```

What data should I put on "Server=" to make my computer B access the database from computer A using a wireless connection.

Using computer B, I can access phpMyAdmin on a browser using 192.168.254.102 as an address.

Computer A (server): 192.168.254.102
Computer B (client): 192.168.254.103

Comment: connectionString="Server=192.168.254.102:3306;Database=studentdb;Uid=thesis;Pwd=12345; 
got an error "no such host is known"

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: try this => `connectionString="Server=192.168.254.102;Port=3306;Database=studentdb;Uid=thesis;
Pwd=12345;"`

Comment: Just add the Computer A (Server) ip and port i.e. connectionString="Server=192.168.254.102;Port=3306;Database=studentdb;Uid=thesis;Pwd=12345";

Comment: i still got the same error after using that line of command, im really depress right now

Comment: @JayChristianFabregas, you need to create firewll inbound rule for port 3306.

Comment: goto => `Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security` => `Inboud Rule` => `New Rule` => `Click on Port radio button` => `Next` => `Type 3306 in textbox` => `Next` => `Allow The Connection` => `Next` => `Next` => `Provide any name to this rule and description` => `Finish`.

Comment: can you guide me how to do that? using windows 10 as of now

Comment: yes read my above comment and do the steps as i mentioned and let me know and use my above commented connection string

Comment: one important the inbound rule is created on your server computer not on client

Comment: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.254.102:3306

Comment: try this `Run -> 'cmd'(as admin) and type "iisreset"` and hit enter key

Comment: if you have any antivirus then try to disabled it

Comment: mysqlexception timeout expired

Comment: means you reached to your server now we need to resolve this issue

Comment: try to add `mySqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 2000` or set it to 0 for unlimited

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio, you might connect to your computer B via Server explorer. There is a nice wizard for it.

Then you can select the server and in the properties windows you will have your connection string.

You might just need to add the password.

Answer (score 0):

If you have placed your database on **Server B** then the connection string will be

```
connectionString="Server=192.168.254.103;Database=studentdb;Uid=thesis;Pwd=12345;
```

Server is the location of the client where database is hosted.

Comment: Database is on Computer A @Rajan Mishra

Comment: Okay Just replace ip.